# What should I use, the 'normal' or the support library?

Tags: android

I often have the problem, that I don't know which library I should use.

Here is an example: I want to make a App which uses `Fragments`
So do I use the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or the `android.app.Fragment`

Another example: `android.view.View.OnClickListener` or `android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

Where to find out which is the one I should use? (Note: This is just one example of making a desicion)

Comment: What is the minimum android API that you want to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments were introduced in api level 11. So if you want to use Fragments below api level 11 you need to use Fragments from Support Library. Your Activity need's to extend `FragmentActivity`. So you will import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

If you are supporting apps api level 11 and above. You can extend `Activity` and use import `android.app.Fragment`

`android.view.View.OnClickListener` is used for views such as button , textview click listener. If you are using dialog then you use `android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

`View.OnClickListener`

Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.

`DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

Interface used to allow the creator of a dialog to run some code when an item on the dialog is clicked..

Answer (score 0):

About the fragments, it depends on your app target. If your app isn't going to support android versions lower than 4.0, then you should use **android.app.Fragment** because those fragments have better functions and flexibility. But if you'll support lower android versions then you should use **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**.

About the ClickListener, if you are setting the listener to a regular view (Button, Image, TextView, etc...) you should use **android.view.View.OnClickListener**. If your are setting the listener to an item inside a dialog, the best option would be **android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener**